# Powershell, trying to output only the path and lastwritetime on directories

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that will output any directory that has not changed in over 90 days.  I want the script to *only* show the entire path name and lastwritetime.  The script that I wrote only shows the path name but not the lastwritetime.  Below is the script.

```sh
Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.mode -match "d"} | Get-Acl | 
    Format-Table @{Label="Path";Expression={Convert-Path $_.Path}},lastwritetime
```

When I run this script, I get the following output:

```
Path                                                        lastwritetime
----                                                        ----------
C:\69a0b021087f270e1f5c
C:\7ae3c67c5753d5a4599b1a
C:\cf
C:\compaq
C:\CPQSYSTEM
C:\Documents and Settings
C:\downloads
```

I discovered that the get-acl command does not have lastwritetime as a member.  So how can I get the needed output for only the path and lastwritetime?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use Get-Acl and for perf use $_.PSIsContainer instead of using a regex match on the Mode property.  Try this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | 
    ? {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-90))} | 
    Format-Table FullName,LastWriteTime -auto
```

You may also want to use -Force to list hidden/system dirs.  To output this data to a file, you have several options:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | 
    ? {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-90))} | 
    Select LastWriteTime,FullName | Export-Csv foo.txt
```

If you are not interested in CSV format try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | 
    ? {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-90))} | 
    Foreach { "{0,23} {1}" -f $_.LastWriteTime,$_.FullName} > foo.txt
```

Also try using Get-Member to see what properties are on files & dirs e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem $Home | Get-Member
```

And to see *all* values do this:

```
Get-ChildItem $Home | Format-List * -force
```

Comment: LastWriteTime changes to child items (files & dirs) only affect the LastWriteTime of the directory that contains these items.

Comment: Adding the -Recurse parameter to Get-ChildItem solve that particular problem.

Comment: Yes I figured that out about the -recurse option after I posted.  But one more question and I will be out of your hair.

Even the format-table has the auto option, when you out put the data to a file the lastwritetime column gets dropped.  Also, using the wrap option makes the output look kinda of messy.

I believe the format-table is automatically taking the column width of the screen and putting it into the file.

Is it possible to created custom column widths using the ft command?

Comment: I updated the answer to show a better way to write the info to file.